# Sending API-key with loadXMLByURL

Tags: xml, api-key

I'm just starting with iOS, so thanks for your patience in advance. I need to send my API-key along with my XML request in order to get access to the data required. Can I use the same methods that I used to create my parser?

First, in my XMLParser.m:

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _matchups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

    return self;
 }
```

Next, in my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"About to retrieve matchups");
   xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]            
   loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/ss/GetHistoricMatchesByLeagueAndSeason.xml"];

   self.title = @"Matchups";
}
```

The URL is x'ed out because I saved and uploaded a sample XML to my personal website to complete my parser before moving on to the API-key. This will be replaced by the asmx.

Ideally, I'd like to send the API-key in the most secure method possible.

Comment: Can anyone help me with sending an API-key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on an Application that sends an App Key to get the XML.  The way It's done in my Application is like this:

```
 // get events with the API from so&so.com
    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"https://www.so&so.com/xml/organizer_list_events?app_key=PNZJKTEM6V4CQdhksUD&id=89019hhx55"];
```

All of this information is found in the websites API section.
I hope this helps